# Component property is not set for key=root

Tags: react-native, react-router

I'm creating a project on react-native and I'm using react-native-router-flux. I get the following error when I try to compile

> Component property is not set for key=root

Here is there code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Router, Scene } from 'react-native-router-flux'
import { Gallery } from './gallery'
import { Events } from './events'

export default class Album extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Scene key='root'>
          <Scene key='gallery' component={Gallery} title='Gallery' />
          <Scene key='events' component={Events} title='Events' />
        </Scene>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Any help? Thanks!

Comment: initial={true} may solve issue. https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/MINI_TUTORIAL.md

Comment: I have tried but I'm getting the same error :/

Comment: may be this https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/issues/569 can help

Comment: Already checked but didn't help so much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have realized the problem was that I was exporting the components I was trying to import in a wrong way. Now it is working.

Edit: The problem was that I was exporting Gallery and Events in a wrong way. Once I fixed the export worked.

The way I exported the components is:

```
export class Gallery extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>This is the Gallery</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope now it's more helpful

Comment: Can you please tell me what was the way? I am getting the same error.

Comment: absolutely useless solution, if you do not specify, HOW did you fix it...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error :
 `[react-native-router-flux] component property is not set for key=root`

my code looks like this :
`<Scene key="loginPage" Component={LoginPage} title="Login" initial={true} />`

this below code doesn't throw error : (component is lower case)

`<Scene key="loginPage" component={LoginPage} title="Login" initial={true} />`